# Ember.js: Failed to create an instance of 'router:main'

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

**Update #2** - This has long been fixed in the latest ember.

**UPDATE** - This has been fixed and I'm pretty sure the fix made it into Ember 1.11.0, so your `export default Router.map( () -> ... )` will actually be correct and not cause this error. Until then, you need to do this:

```
Router.map(...)
export default Router
```

This is because `Router.map` does not return the `Router` instance.

=====================

I'm getting this error in my Ember-cli project:
**Uncaught Error: Failed to create an instance of 'router:main'. Most likely an improperly defined class or an invalid module export**

My app/router.js file is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

export default Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
}).map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
});
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of fiddling, I found out that Ember.Router.map does not return an instance of Ember Router. This is also **invalid**:

```
Router = Router.map(function(){ this.route('a'); });
export default Router;
```

The solution is to simply avoid using the return value from `.map` and export the proper Ember Router instance instead:

```
Router.map(function(){ this.route('a'); });
export default Router;
```

Hopefully this gets fixed in 2.0: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9966